# Battlefield 1942 not running

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-1942

I used to play Battlefield 1942 all the time. It worked fine. Then one day, It refused to run, saying that I need to log in with administrator privileges in order to run it. I was already logged in as an administrator, so this line greatly confused me. Does anyone know of this problem? If so, is there any way that I can fix this?

Comment: Have you tried running the program as Administrator. In most Windows computers you can right-click on the program and then select run as admin.

Comment: I have. It had a different output, now that I think of it. When I did that, it gave me a loading cursor for a few seconds. Then it stopped. According to task manager, It was not running the program at that time, ore even attempting to do so.

Comment: which version of windows are you running? you may need to run in a compatibility mode for an older version

Comment: windows 7 home premium (service pack 1)

Comment: There are a number of things that could cause this: OS updates, graphics card updates, etc. If you remember the two dates (last successful play and first unsuccessful play) you could look at your [Event Log in Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) which might yield what was installed / uninstalled / changed. Otherwise you could try the [Windows compatibility troubleshooter](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-AU/windows-8/older-programs-compatible-version-windows).

Comment: how do i view event logs? oh, and the troubleshooter doesn't work.

Comment: also, after further investigation, none of my EA games work any more. They all have the same problem

Comment: Sounds like the issue might be with Origin or something.  If no EA games work, the common thread would be the culprit.

Comment: Do you have this on a physical disc or is it digital? I'm seeing similar issues related to physical copies of this game.

Comment: I have a physical disk. according to someone on Moongamers (another site), there is a patch that will fix this issue. However, the patch says that I don't have a copy of battlefield to patch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like Microsoft introduced a sort of DRM blocker that has been interfering with people who play PC games with old retail discs. Since you said you are using a physical disc, I have found a few possible solutions for you.

[Here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-gaming/please-login-with-administrator-privileges-and-try/159d1eff-34da-423c-814b-6357b86a7360) are a couple specifically for Windows 7:

> There are several methods  to get around this on Win 7:
>
> 1. Uninstall two Windows 'Security Updates' - KB2919355 & 3086255 -  and stop using automatic Windows Updates
>      so you can block these updates (hiding them may work for now, but they may sneak back) from installing when
>      you do updates in future.
> 2. Leave the update and use noCD fixes/hacks for any game that gets blocked.

Comment: Let me know if neither of these work and I'll keep looking.

Comment: I've uninstalled 3086255, but I'm having troubles finding the other one, I'm going to restart my computer now to apply the update.

Comment: @JohnKlubertanz fingers crossed!

Comment: You my good sir are brilliant! It worked, and now I can play again.